# SQL Server - Group By and Order By?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-order-by

I have the following table. For each rsptxt_question_fk, I want to get the rsptxt_text_response where rsptxt_id_pk is the highest.
Meaning that I want my output to be (48, abc, 1, 33) and (51, def, 8, 22). Does anyone know how to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: That's exactly it @Larnu, thank you very much!